# Baffling problem with BingMaps RouteService web service reference

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, service-reference

Hope someone can help me - this is driving me *crazy*!!

I'm developing a WP7 app that uses Bing Maps and I need to use the RouteService webservice (found here: http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc) in order to create a route of points visited but when I finish adding the service reference I  get the following error and I can't do anything with the web service:

Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'RouteService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.   D:\Projects\WindowsPhone\MapApp\Service References\RouteService\Reference.svcmap.

The crazy thing is I have another demo project I downloaded which already had the reference to this exact same web service and it works fine.  But if I try to update that reference it then gives me the same error!

I have tried this on two different Windows 7 machines, one with the very latest updates to the WP7 dev tools and one without and it does it on both machines.  I've also tried rebooting with no luck.... it's like something's changed somewhere but I have no idea what!

Can someone please try adding this service reference and letting me if they get the same issue - I am completely baffled as to what is happening here!

TIA....

Mike

Answer (score 0):

No defitinive answer but I hit the same problem with a project because I already had a service reference in it before the Bing Map routing one. I ended up create a new project with the Bing Map service reference and unload the project and copy the content of the relevant sections of the csproj file in my project's file (csproj).

There's also a couple files in a directory inside Service References subfolder.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I also posted on the apphub forum and someone suggested jsut starting from scratch in a new project and adding the existing pages and code - once I did that it was fine.  I'm going to try and reproduce this at some point so I can report it as a VS2010 bug.